# syn-keyword with control characters?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, conceal, control-character

(I know the goals are dumb, and I know I could set `ffs=unix,dos` to not see `^M`; I'm just trying to understand more about vim).

I was playing around with vim keywords, because I want to conceal certain things.
I was able to successfully hide a keyword with syntax like this:

```
syn keyword Windows happy conceal cchar=A
set conceallevel=2
```

This would successfully create a keyword group called "Windows" that conceals `happy` and replaces it with `A` in my text.

I *cannot* do the same with control characters:

```
syn keyword Windows ^M conceal cchar=A
set conceallevel=2
```

Whether I type out <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, I am unable to conceal a control character.

Nothing in `:help syn` mentions anything about control characters being excluded (it only says I can't have `cchar` be a control character).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot do the same with control characters.

When you use `syn keyword` Vim is actually trying to match *keywords*, which are defined as sequences of characters included in [`'iskeyword'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27).

From [`:help :syn-keyword`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-keyword):

> Don't forget that a keyword can only be recognized if all the characters are included in the `'iskeyword'` option. If one character isn't, the keyword will never be recognized.

You can have that recognize a `^M` by adding it to `'iskeyword'`:

```
setlocal iskeyword+=13
syn keyword Windows ^M conceal cchar=A
set conceallevel=2
```

(Note that `^M` above is entered as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.)

But note that `syn keyword` will only recognize `^M` when it appears on its own, surrounded by whitespace, as a keyword, and not when it's right at the end of another word, which would be more typical...

A better solution is to use `syn match` for this case, which uses a regular expression to define a match. In that case, you can use `'\r'` as a pattern to match any `^M` anywhere in the line:

```
syn match Windows '\r' conceal cchar=A
set conceallevel=2
```